# Pass milliseconds from timer to input on form submit with jQuery Stopwatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am attempting to get the milliseconds value from this jQuery Stopwatch library https://github.com/robcowie/jquery-stopwatch

The millisecond value is not documented, apart from in a GitHub issue that states

> Make elapsed milliseconds available in data. #2 …
>   Get at it with $().data('stopwatch')['elapsed']

I have attempted to access the milliseconds in this way through the following code (it's within Wordpress, hence the lack of $ signs)

```
<a href="#" id="test"><h2>Test</h2></a>
<script>
    jQuery( "#test" ).click(function() {
        alert(jQuery().data('stopwatch')['elapsed']);
    });
</script>
```

But I am getting the following console error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elapsed' of null

The stopwatch is initialised through this code

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.quizTimerSpan').stopwatch({startTime: 0, format: '{MM}:{ss}'}).stopwatch('start') }, 8500);
});
```

The first problem is actually getting the millisecond value, and then actually passing it through to an input value on a button click. I assume the following code will work once I actually get the millisecond value, but I'm pretty new to jQuery so would be good to get this sanity checked as well.

```
jQuery( "#question" ).submit(function( event ) {
      jQuery( "#timerValue" ).val(.data('stopwatch')['elapsed']));
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML form element...

```
<input type="hidden" name="timerValue" id="timerValue" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to achieve what I wanted to do by switching to the jQuery Timer library from here http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

The following code did exactly what I needed...

```
function pad(number, length) {
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {str = '0' + str;}
    return str;
}
function formatTime(time) {
    time = time / 10;
    var min = parseInt(time / 6000),
    sec = parseInt(time / 100) - (min * 60),
    hundredths = pad(time - (sec * 100) - (min * 6000), 2);
    // Switch for more accurate output
    // return (min > 0 ? pad(min, 2) : "00") + ":" + pad(sec, 2) + ":" + hundredths;
          return (min > 0 ? pad(min, 2) : "00") + ":" + pad(sec, 2);
}

var quizStopwatch = new (function() {
    var $stopwatch;
    var incrementTime = 70;
    var currentTime = 0;

$(function() {
    $stopwatch = $('.quizTimerSpan');
    quizStopwatch.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);
});

function updateTimer() {
    var timeString = formatTime(currentTime);
    $stopwatch.html(timeString);
    currentTime += incrementTime;
    document.title = timeString;
    $("#timerValue").val(currentTime);
}
});
```

As a bonus, I am also able to set the title of the page on each interval.